# multiple html as output and one xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt, hyperlink

I am converting a XML to HTML using XSLT. 
The output of should have 2 HTML files linked with each other. 
In the first html there will be a list of data and once I click on a particular data I should get the details of that particular data in other html file. I need to use xslt for this.

I have used Saxon to generate multiple htmls but I am able to perform the linking functionality. Any ideas on how to do this?

My input look like this

```
<a:file>
<a:id>33</a:id>
<a:name>hello</a:name>
<a:school>mumbai public</a:school>
<a:marks>80</a:marks>
</a:file>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Saxon 9 or any XSLT 2.0 processor can generate multiple result documents with one stylesheet, as for linking two documents there is nothing difficult about this, you would simply use an HTML `a` element with a `href` attribute linking to the other document.

If you need help on this for a particular data then please post a small but representative XML input sample and also the HTML you want to create.

[edit]

Assuming you have an input document with a couple of those `a:file` elements and you want to create one main HTML document listing all `a:names` linking to separate files listing the details you can solve that as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//a:file" mode="doc"/>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Data list</h1>
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//a:file"/>
      </ul>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:file">
  <li>
    <a href="{a:id}.html">
      <xsl:value-of select="a:name"/>
    </a>
  </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:file" mode="doc">
  <xsl:result-document href="{a:id}.html">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Details of <xsl:value-of select="a:name"/></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
             <xsl:apply-templates mode="thead"/>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
             <xsl:apply-templates mode="doc"/>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:file/*" mode="doc">
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:file/*" mode="thead">
  <th>
   <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
  </th>
</xsl:template>
```

Untested but should give you an idea. If you need more help then please show more details of your input and wanted output, I had to make up the format of both the main HTML result (used a list there) and the details files (used a table there).

[edit 2]
Assuming the complete input sample is

```
<a:files xmlns:a="http://example.com/a">
<a:file>
<a:id>33</a:id>
<a:name>hello</a:name>
<a:school>mumbai public</a:school>
<a:marks>80</a:marks>
</a:file>
</a:files>
```

and the complete stylesheet sample is

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:a="http://example.com/a"
  exclude-result-prefixes="a"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//a:file" mode="doc"/>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Data list</h1>
      <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//a:file"/>
      </ul>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:file">
  <li>
    <a href="{a:id}.html">
      <xsl:value-of select="a:name"/>
    </a>
  </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:file" mode="doc">
  <xsl:result-document href="{a:id}.html">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Details of <xsl:value-of select="a:name"/></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
             <xsl:apply-templates mode="thead"/>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
             <xsl:apply-templates mode="doc"/>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:file/*" mode="doc">
  <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:file/*" mode="thead">
  <th>
   <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
  </th>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then when I use Saxon 9.4 HE from the command line doing e.g. `java -jar saxon9he.jar input.xml sheet.xsl -o:result.html` I get two result files, the main of course being `result.html`, the other being `33.html` which look as follows:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Example</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Data list</h1>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="33.html">hello</a></li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>




<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Details of hello</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>

               <th>id</th>

               <th>name</th>

               <th>school</th>

               <th>marks</th>

            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>

               <td>33</td>

               <td>hello</td>

               <td>mumbai public</td>

               <td>80</td>

            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

So that works fine for me, both as far as the number of files is concerned as well as for the linking working inside the browser.

Comment: yeah I did the same using a and href but how to display the information of a particular record on the second html. Suppose i click on a link named 'details' so when I click on details I should get only a particular information not everything.

Comment: i edited my question and placed a sample XML input. In this on one page I am displaying all the names and when I click on name, I should be redirected to another page displaying complete details.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added a code sample showing how you could approach that, it generates the primary transformation result as an HTML document showing all items and then links to further result documents showing details of a single item.

Comment: You can run that with Saxon 9 or other XSLT 2.0 processors (like AltovaXML or XmlPrime). If you want details on how to run a stylesheet with Saxon 9 then consult http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xsl/intro.xml.

Comment: doesn't work properly with Saxon. I just got one output file and rest nothing

Comment: Well I have written code snippets against snippets of your code but even when I do the work of adding the necessary elements to get complete samples the code does its job. I will edit and show you what I have.